# C# Printing suddenly problematic on creators update

Tags: c#, printing, windows-10

i created a cheque writing program using C#.net and has been using it for several years already. It can print three types of documents (cheques, check vouchers, cheque issued summary)

however, after updating to windows 10 creators update, one of the three documents does not print anymore - and no errors are being thrown. the printer just indicates that it is online. I can validate that it is still working on a windows 10 machine that has not yet been updated to the creators update.

I tried running the program in debug mode trying to find out if there is an error, but none was found. the program flowed normally as if nothing was wrong.

I even tried reducing the code to the bare minimum, it still does not work.

do you guys know any changes in the creators update that might have affected the C# printing?

Comment: please provide your code you tried, .. i think the windows 7 8 10 , will make a problem for the printing in c#.

Comment: seem to have found the problem. it is related to paper size. if the size is smaller than the printer's minimum it rejects the job. unlike before where it just prints it regardless. Do you know any work around? The cheques we use are below the minimum of the printer so, before, I just use an offset in the program to handle it but now the print job is being rejected by the printer. do not know if it is the new printer driver or windows 10. i changed the printer driver because the creators update uninstalled them

Comment: which type of printer you using and which type of paper.( better use A4 as default. )

Comment: our cheques are 3 in x 8 in and I use canon g2000

Comment: ok u can custom and make the report page size and try to print it.

Comment: i think it is the printer driver not the creators update. I tried it on a computer not on creators update but updated the printer driver. it did not work as well

Comment: i am now trying to modify the main program to just use the Letter paper size and adjust the margins to still be able to print very small cheques (3" x 8")

Comment: ok , check with this one and update ur result.

Comment: got it working, I explained the work around below. Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. it is not the creators update of windows 10. Instead it is the new printer driver that I installed (I have to reinstall the printer because the windows 10 update seems to have uninstalled it). The new printer driver apparently blocked paper sizes that is below its minimum - the printer just hangs as if printing but nothing comes out. I do not know if this is a bug on the driver or it was intentional.

Nevertheless, got it working again. the work around I used to force the printer to print smaller than minimum paper sizes is

- First to indicate that the paper is any normal paper size (such as Letter 8.5 x 11) larger than the small paper size that I needed.
- Then just make the margins large enough so that the space remaining is the small paper that I need.

Of course you must consider what type of printer you have. My printer feeds the paper centered (as in the paper is align by left and right alignment clips). If the printer is right aligned (only a left clip aligns the paper), corresponding adjustments must be made in the margins (such as no left margins)

Also when computing for the proper margins, you must consider the printer's hard margin (I think it may be hardware limitation).

Comment: good, i think it is not might be the printer instillation or hardware problem. some thing else. anyway congrats for find the solutions.